# Git pull is very slow... Why?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

Note I have studied the [git-is-very-very-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055506/git-is-very-very-slow) question, but in their case the reason was big binary files - while in my repository there is PHP/JS/HTML/CSS only code (no binaries) and the biggest file in the repository is around 800 KB.

I've changed one file (a few lines), then `git add .` and `git commit -m "msg"`, then `git push origin master`.

On some other machine, when I do `git pull origin master` it downloads a few MiB of data, and it takes more than 2 minutes to calculate the delta and apply changes. Something is terribly wrong here.

I suspect some recent operations may cause this:

recently, I've accidentally added many vendor assets (`bower_components` assets)
when I realized it, I've used `git rm` to remove them from repository (and ofcourse, `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` to upstream).

That was a few days ago and the problems I have right now started happeing around that time.

I have two questions:

- Why this is happeing?
- How can I fix my repository?

Note: I am the only one useing and pushing to this repo.

Comment: try `git ls-files` to view all files checked into git. May give an idea of what's happening

Comment: there is 530 files total.. I've reviewed the list, and all of them should be there (and none of them is bigger than 800KB)

Comment: Did the other machine already have the changes where you removed the vendor assets? If not, it may have needed to pull in the revisions where they were added and deleted, since just `git rm`ing them leaves the additions in the history. Does it remain slow if you do a subsequent pull of new changes?

Comment: after accidentally adding files, I did a pull on target machine... this is when I realized my mistake.. so I went to my source machine, did `git rm`, pushed upstream, and then went back to my target machine and pulled

Comment: however, ever since that moment, every subsequent pull on target machine has been slow... I understand that it had to download the files the first time it pulled that commit.. but I would expect it to work fast on all subsequenst pulls (regardless of me doing or not the `git rm`)

Comment: PS. all changes are made on Source machine, then pushed to VersionControl server, and then pulled on Target machines --> only the pulls on Target machine are slow, pushes work fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in `EmberJS` app directory. It contained `node_modules` and `bower_components` directories which kept third-party libraries used by `GruntJS` to build my JS and CSS assets.

Each of these contained many files and directories.. considering that the dependency tree contained hundreds of libraries of size varying from small (few files) to big fat (many files).

After removing these directories and ignoring them, the git repository works fast again.

Answer (score 52):

I had the same issue. For me this was a IPv4/IPv6 issue. I fixed it forcing SSH to use IPv4.

Set "AddressFamily inet" in /etc/ssh/ssh_config to force IPv4 connection. Then restart ssh client `sudo service ssh restart`

More info [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Slow-SSH-clone-pull-push/qaq-p/953843).

Comment: This is the solution!! I finally solved the problem by this. You could try `git fetch -4` or `git push -4` to see if actually solves the problem before you add it to ssh_config.

Comment: @Arst  what does `git fetch -4` means?

Comment: @kajibu it means using IPv4. can be either -4, --ipv4. for IPv6: -6 --ipv6.

Comment: This solution worked for me. But there is no need for a service restart.

Comment: @Arst solution saved me so much pain. No need to restart

Comment: In my case git had been working just fine. I was running on a Raspberry Pi 4 and then one day it starts taking forever. I'm ssh'ing in from a LInux box to the Pi maybe there was an update to SSH on Linux that caused it, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: it might be that the DNS is giving broken AAAA records. solving the ipv6 problem with the network administrator can help other clients.

Answer (score 19):

I have had the same issue when I was dealing with thousands of small files.
The thing that fixed it for me was to set the postbuffer in git repo's config

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Instead of uploading with 18KB/s it suddenly went the full bandwidth

Answer (score 13):

I tried all solutions in this thread with no luck. I tried using git protocol 2 at the suggestion of a coworker, which ended up being very effective (went from waiting 3 minutes for pulls/pushes to start to a few seconds)

```
git config --global protocol.version 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar experience -- git pull and push suddenly starting to run EXTREMELY slowly, taking ten minutes or more, both on my local Mac OSX and on my Linux / Apache server.  I deleted the local copy of the repo on my Mac, and recloned it, and it started to run fine.  Did the same thing on the server, and all is well.  I suppose it was somehow corrupted?

Answer (score 4):

Just incase if someone is stumble upon this thread, before deleting your .git folder, try to restart your wifi, that may be just your wifi connection issue.

Comment: I'm not getting why this answer downvoted that much. This could be the solution for some people. Routers/modems tend to fail from time to time, causing performance or connectivity problems.

Comment: Since this issue can be caused by lack of bandwidth, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not only the protocol v2 will help, but the commit graph ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65272203/6309)) will help too.

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), loading of ref tips to prepare for common ancestry negotiation in "[`git fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b2be06e04c5dba2fc25d2eb0cc2bd85d469e350/Documentation/git-fetch-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch-pack))</sup> has been optimized by taking advantage of the commit graph when available.

See [commit 3e5e6c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e5e6c6e94f09973d3a72049aad09fd2131a3648) (04 Aug 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b2be06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b2be06e04c5dba2fc25d2eb0cc2bd85d469e350), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e5e6c6e94f09973d3a72049aad09fd2131a3648): speed up loading of refs via commit graph
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When doing reference negotiation, git-fetch-pack(1) is loading all refs from disk in order to determine which commits it has in common with the remote repository.
> This can be quite expensive in repositories with many references though: in a real-world repository with around 2.2 million refs, fetching a single commit by its ID takes around 44 seconds.
>
> Dominating the loading time is decompression and parsing of the objects which are referenced by commits.
> Given the fact that we only care about commits (or tags which can be peeled to one) in this context, there is thus an easy performance win by switching the parsing logic to make use of the commit graph in case we have one available.
> Like this, we avoid hitting the object database to parse these commits but instead only load them from the commit-graph.
> This results in a significant performance boost when executing [`git-fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5e6c6e94f09973d3a72049aad09fd2131a3648/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> in said repository with 2.2 million refs:
>
> ```
> Benchmark #1: HEAD~: git fetch $remote $commit
>   Time (mean ± σ):     44.168 s ±  0.341 s    [User: 42.985 s, System: 1.106 s]
>   Range (min … max):   43.565 s … 44.577 s    10 runs
>
> Benchmark #2: HEAD: git fetch $remote $commit
>   Time (mean ± σ):     19.498 s ±  0.724 s    [User: 18.751 s, System: 0.690 s]
>   Range (min … max):   18.629 s … 20.454 s    10 runs
>
> Summary
>   'HEAD: git fetch $remote $commit' ran
>     2.27 ± 0.09 times faster than 'HEAD~: git fetch $remote $commit'
> ```

Comment: What does this mean? Are you saying that using a newer Git version speeds up fetching, or is there anything specific that I need to do?

Comment: @cdauth More recent Git versions are faster. This answer mentions an improvement done with Git 2.34. Any version equal or more recent than 2.34 will benefit from that evolution.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem with ipv4/ipv6. So using following commands, it resolved for me.

```
git pull -4
git fetch -4
```

Or

```
git pull --ipv4
git fetch --ipv4
```

You can also set up a `~/.ssh/config` for this with following snippet

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    AddressFamily inet
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Linux Mint and GitLab and GitHub. I had no problems with pull/fetch before, but suddenly I only had problems with GitLab. After reading this thread, I understood that it might be related to SSH and IPv4/6.

When I saw on https://whatismyipaddress.com/ that the website could not find my IPv6 address, I restarted my router. Now everything is fine.

so before you start changing setting try this simple solution

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the git protocol you use.
I switched the gitlab project url to ***https***, and the slowness nightmare was gone!

You can edit your repo `.git/config` and change to https url, or via command:

```
git remote set-url https://{server}@gitlab.com/{user}/{project}.git`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways in this thread, but without any luck. And it came to me that I should try pulling with VS Code, as it helped me in git related issue before. And it finished pulling literally in one second.

I don't have profound knowledge of how git works. So I can't really explain why. Maybe it's because VS Code is embeded with a different version of git.

Comment: Before this, I was stuck at git fetch/pull: `Receiving objects:  93% (228/246), 620.28 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s`

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a repository that had a lot of remote branches. One thing that helped me was remove all the remote tracking branches except `origin/main`:

```
git branch -r --no-contains "$(git rev-parse --quiet origin/main)" | xargs -I{} git branch -rd "{}"
git gc --prune=now
```

This reduced the size of my `.git` directory from 16 GiB to 4.4 GiB. Instead of `git pull`, I now use this:

```
git fetch origin main
git merge origin/main
```

While `git fetch` is still slow, it has to download so much less data that it takes much less time.