# Unable to Git Push, using https protocol

Tags: git, github, git-push, repo

so I am trying to do my initial commit (a small .gitignore file, and an empty .h file and an empty .cpp file, basically an extremely small commit). I have tried a lot. I thought it might be a problem with IPv4 versus IPv6 per this stack overflow discussion: [Git pull is very slow... Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040246/git-pull-is-very-slow-why/45722964).

I tried to push using ipv4.

```
$ git push --ipv4 -u -v origin main
Pushing to https://github.com/brian-campbell-said-mba18/leetcode-valid-palindrome-ii.git
```

It always fails to push to the remote repo in github.

Also for reference here are some of my git config -global settings (I'm not going to show some of the personal info for obvious reasons)

```
$ git config --global --list
user.name= NOT-GIVEN
user.email=NOT-GIVEN
core.editor=code --wait
credential.helper=wincred
protocl.version=2
```

So visual studio code is my default IDE. I also tried fiddling around with credential.helper and changing the protocol to version 2 (per some advice from other stack overflow solutions).

I've been using git and github consistently for about two years now and have never encountered anything like this. It's strange.

Also, I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 and Windows Subsytem for Linux (so I could use Docker). Could these installations have anything to do with this?

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help!!!!!!!!!!!!!

PS. I tried another experiment. I took a repo that I successfully pushed to github a month ago and tried to clone it in an empty local directory, and I had the same problem.

Comment: What does "fails" mean? You say push and git says... what?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. So essentially, I get the below message and I never get an error message (I assume that my computer is trying to push but just never pushes)

MESSAGE IN COMMAND LINE: 'Pushing to https://github.com/brian-campbell-said-mba18/leetcode-valid-palindrome-ii.git'

Comment: I get that message, and then I just have a cursor that blinks forever in my command line

Comment: Sounds like a variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic