# git branch switch takes half a minute?

Tags: macos, git, performance

Got an more powerful and fresh machine from work, starting installing dev tools and this is simply nightmare, I've never ever had **performance issues with git** on the old machine. Here it is beyond reason:

```
ons-mbp:spec ALE$ time git checkout fsfs

Switched to branch 'fsfs'

real    0m30.080s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.006s

    ons-mbp:spec ALE$ time git checkout master

Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

real    0m30.083s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.007s
```

Tried reinstalling different git version, tried via homebrew and manually - zero effect.

Can anyone provide a hint?

OS ver: 10.9.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [git is very very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055506/git-is-very-very-slow)

Comment: Might not be your fault.  If the repo has a habit of storing large binary files, then you've got to deal with that at some point or pay the cost in performance.

Comment: found the issue(google deep scavenging - not a duplicate, will post right away)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing fresh install completely forgot about setting global user details.

```
 git config --global user.name "Test Test"
 git config --global user.email "testgmail.com"
```

Credits to:

["I normally do this right away when setting up my account on a new machine. The fresh install didn't trigger that reflex. I'm surprised that this is needed to keep git from preforming silly DNS lookups but no big deal."](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1666008)

```
ons-mbp:spec ALE$ time git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.005s
ons-mbp:spec ALE$ time git checkout fsfs
Switched to branch 'fsfs'

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Saved from heart attack.