# Profiling "git add ." - Why is it slow?

Tags: git

Assume project where no add and commit has been done for a long time. 
I do `git add .` but it takes too much time. 
I  would like to estimate which files/directories are most expensive in the current case. 
I have a good `.gitignore` file which works sufficiently but, still sometimes, I have too much and/or something too difficult to be added and committed to Git.

I have often directories which size is from 300GB to 2 TB in my directories. 
Although excluding them by `directory/*` and `directory/` in `.gitignore`, the addition is slow.

How can you estimate which directories/files are too expensive to be committed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Git slowness is generally from large binary files. This isn't because they're binary, just because binary files tend to be large and more complex to compress & diff.

Based on your edit indicating the file sizes, I suspect this is your problem.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3055506/1445366) offer a few solutions: removing them from source control, manually running `git gc`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

"`git add`" needs to internally run "`diff-files`" equivalent,

With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), the codepath learned the same optimization as "`diff-files`" has to run `lstat(2)` in parallel to find which paths have been updated in the working tree.

See [commit d1664e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1664e73ad96aa08735bf81d48ec0fb6d196cc3e) (02 Nov 2018) by [Ben Peart (`benpeart`)](https://github.com/benpeart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9235a6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9235a6ce47f012cd8fcfa80117fed29790bb929b), 13 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### `add`: speed up `cmd_add()` by utilizing `read_cache_preload()`
>
> During an "`add`", a call is made to `run_diff_files()` which calls `check_removed()` for each index-entry.
>   The `preload_index()` code distributes some of the costs across multiple threads.
>
> Because the files checked are restricted to pathspec, adding individual files makes no measurable impact but **on a Windows repo with ~200K files, '`git add .`' drops from 6.3 seconds to 3.3 seconds for a 47% savings**.